# i didn't find the root of my spring project (in sts)

Tags: spring, project, root

images can't be charged by pages.

Here are the contenet contents of src attribut in `img` tag .

src="../images/myimage.jpg"

Thank you for your help.

my project skelton:

> project_name/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images/myimage  ----------
>   project_name/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/mypages

Comment: Did you confiture your [ResourceServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ResourceServlet.html)? How does `/` relate to the images folder? Do *any* resources work (e.g. HTML, CSS). Why are JSP views inside `images/` folder?

Comment: Sorry,
my project skelton is like that:
project_name/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images/my image ------
project_name/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/page1.jsp -------project_name/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/page2.jsp

Comment: Please edit your question to include the extra information, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: i do it. i wish the problem is light

Comment: You still don't include enough information to diagnose your problem (I asked some hopefully helpful questions in my first comment) and I see you edited your question to change the path from `/` for `../`. Any reason for that?